# Keyboard shortcut to access Arrows sub-section in Windows' Character Map?

Tags: windows, unicode

Since there's [no fast and reliable way](https://superuser.com/questions/170448/how-can-i-get-keyboard-shortcuts-for-certain-characters-listed-in-character-map) to enter Unicode characters and typing codes is just too cumbersome, I was wondering if there were an easy way to access a given sub-section in Windows' Character Map?

[image]

It's only 2015 :-/

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know how to customize `charmap` to achieve your (intelligible) need, but `↕`=`Alt`18, `↨`=`Alt`23, `↑`=`Alt`24, `↓`=`Alt`25, `→`=`Alt`26, `←`=`Alt`27, `↔`=`Alt`29

Comment: Thanks much. I didn't know those shortcuts:

http://www.irongeek.com/alt-numpad-ascii-key-combos-and-chart.html